# Find a set satisfying a condition

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Show $\exists$ a set T, where T $\in$ $\mathbb{Z^+}$, such that for **every** positive integer $a$, $\frac{|T \cap\{a,2a,...,na\}|}{n}\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$. **Hint**: Choose a subset at random such that there $\exists$ an event of probability 1 that satisfies the claim above. Answer would be a deterministic set.

Initially, I thought we could choose $T$ to be the set of even numbers and show that the limit would be $\frac{1}{2}$. However, that fails for $a=2$. Also, I do not know how to use the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural experiment should consist of throwing countably many (independent) coins and to define $S$ to be the random set of all integers $i$ such that the $i$-th throw led to heads. Then, for any $a$, the claimed convergence (with $S(\omega)$ in the role of $T$) holds almost surely due to the SLLN. Call $T_a$ the subset of $\Omega$ such that the convergence holds. Then $T = \bigcap_{a > 0} T_a$ should do the trick.

Comment: Will the result be true if the sequence was just increasing positive integers rather than {a, 2a, ...na}?

Comment: The point is: We ask the set $T$ to satisfy a certain property (depending on $a$) for a countable number of $a$'s. Then, if we define a random set $S$ for which we show that this property holds almost surely for any $a$, then we know that it holds almost surely for all $a$ (because the number of $a$'s is countable). In that sense you can exchange {a, 2a, ... na} by any set of $n$ integers you like, as long as the total number of sets remains countable.